# Translate date format in django: technical message id?

Tags: django, internationalization, date-format

I'm working on a site that displays dates, and is in several languages via i18n. 
I'm displaying dates with a filter (sometimes I want only the day, only the hour, etc.)

I've read the last paragraph of this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/i18n/, and from what I understand I'm supposed to be able to specify the formats I want in the django.po locale and use them in the template filter ?

It doesn't seem to work though.

```
 {{ date_start|date:"{% trans "DATE_HOUR_ONLY" %}" }}
```

With in the django.po for english language:

```
 msgid "DATE_HOUR_ONLY"
 msgstr "%P"
```

This completely blows up though... 
And using single quotes instead of doubles (**{{ date_start|date:"{% trans 'DATE_HOUR_ONLY' %}" }}**) doesn't blow up but displays this :

```
 {% 31Fri, 17 May 2013 00:00:00 -0500a.m.500 'FriAMCDTMay_00-05001368766800R_-0500MayFalse2013' %}
```

I can't find any concrete example online on how to proceed. Without the filters, the date switches correctly depending on the language, because of how DATE_FORMAT is set in my settings.py

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a bit of wandering around, this worked:

```
  {{ date_start|date:_('DATE_WITH_HOUR') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try Django formats.py

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/formatting/

For example , i have a formats folder in my project, don't forget the "**init**.py"
if you want add a different locale,only need add a folder like 'zh_TW' in the 'en' same level

```
mysite/
    formats/
        __init__.py
        en/
            __init__.py
            formats.py
```

the formats.py look like

```
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'Y/m/d'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y/m/d G:i:s'
```

and in my template.html

```
{ now | date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }
```

that can change by your locale, hope the solution will help you :)